# Searching in string collection

Tags: c#, linq, search, collections

I have string in this format:
`"a = 23, b = 432, f = 321, gfs = 413, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314, (...etc...)"` - about 30 elements

I need to have possibility of searching in many of that strings accordingly 4 elements, e.g: a, b, d, k.

For example query verbally: `give me all string where a = 3, b, = 2, d = 31, k = 1`

What kind of collection should I use? Want kind of class should I create? Any ideas?

Comment: so what will be the result of your above query?

Answer (score 1):

if you know that your values are unique, I would construct a hash table where the left hand side of the equal is your key and the right is your value. this will help you avoiding any string formation that might change, for example extra spaces etc.

here is some code sample

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "a = 23, b = 432, f = 321, gfs = 413, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314";
    Dictionary<string,string> dictionary = ConstructDictionary(str);
    // Now you can find what you want in your dictionary
}

private static Dictionary<string,string> ConstructDictionary(string str)
{
    string[] pairs = str.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // this will give you all the pairs X = Y
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string pair in pairs)
    {
        string[] keyValue = pair.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // this will create an array of size 2 where 
        array[0] = key and array[1] = value;
        string key = keyValue[0].Trim();
        string value = keyValue[1].Trim();
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: You're recommending that he creates a dictionary for every string that he has to search?

Comment: The OP wants to search through _many_ strings for _particular values_ and wants _all the strings_ that satisfy those values.

Comment: @NominSim Then you'd want to parse each string into a dictionary, using the method provided, and filter on the dictionaries containing the key/value pairs needed.  It's still a good approach, even if it's incomplete.  In my eyes it does enough that the OP can take it from here.

Comment: he said that he have around 30 values "...about 30 elements" from the format of X = Y , ...., X30 = Y30. Than he gets another string that will need to search for their values as in find a,b,d & k

Comment: @Nir But there are N strings, each with 30 values, meaning N dictionaries.

Comment: @Servy where did you get that you have N strings each with 30 values ?

Comment: @Nir *"give me all string where a = 3, b, = 2, d = 31, k = 1"*  He wants all of the strings that have `a` set to three, and `b` set to two, etc.

Comment: @Nir The OP is clearly not a native English speaker, so it's not very clear; while I'm not entirely convinced that's what he want's, that's clearly how everyone else is interpreting the question.

Comment: @Servy - that is why I said that if his keys are unique. So what you are saying is that you might have a = 3 & bca = 3  and therefore you will output a = 3 & bca = 3 (because bca contains a and is equal to 3 ?)

Comment: @Nir No.  Why don't you read the other answers.  From the answer it's clear how they interpret what the question is.  [Nomin's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11364847/1159478) in particular.

Comment: @Servy - I did read all the answers, and I still not sure how you guys got that he will have multiple strings (hence s1,s2,s3 from Nomin's solution), but this doesn't matter. He can choose whatever works best for him. Thanks for trying to explain!

Comment: @Servy That's what I asked in the beginning if he was recommending putting each string into a dictionary. It is definitely a working solution, however it seems like the overhead of creating a dictionary, and doing a look-up might not be the best solution.

Comment: @NominSim - i'm a he not a she :D. Also, if you have multiple strings the dictionary will still work. The only difference will be that the value of the dictionary will be an array (or a list which than you will be able to find all the values that you are looking for, for a given key. plus you will be able to add the string name (A,B,C... or 1,2,3....) in case you need to (by changing the list to be a different structure

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it using an auxiliary function:

```
private static bool HasAll(string s, string[] keys, int[] vals) {
    if (keys.Length != vals.Length) throw new ArgumentException("vals");
    var tt = s.Split(new[] {' ', ',', '='});
    for(var i = 0 ; i != keys.Length ; i++) {
        var pos = Array.IndexOf(tt, keys[i]));
        if (pos < 0 || pos == vals.Length-1 || !tt[i+1].Equals(vals[i].ToString())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can use LINQ to get the items like this:

```
var keys = new[] {"a", "b", "d", "k"};
var vals = new[] {3, 2, 31, 1};
var res = data.Where(str => HasAll(str, keys, vals)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the quesiton correctly, this should do it

1) Create a dictionary where the key is the full string and the value is the split pieces of the string

2) Check for intersection of the criteria with the pieces. Intersection size is same as criteria size and we have a match.

```
[TestMethod]
public void FindValuesInStrings() {

  var strings = new[] {
     "a = 23, b = 432, f = 321, gfs = 11, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314",   //A
     "a = 12, b = 123, f = 456, gfs = 11, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314",   //B
     "a = 11, b = 456, f = 789, gfs = 413, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314",  //C
     "a = 23, b = 789, f = 12,  gfs = 13, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314",   //D
  };


   var dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
   foreach (var str in strings) {
      dict.Add(str, str.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()));
   }


   // finds the two entries where a = 23 (A & D)
   var criteria = new[] { "a = 23" };
   var found = dict.Where(entry => 
       entry.Value.Intersect(criteria).Count() == criteria.Count()).Select(entry => entry.Key);

   Assert.AreEqual(2, found.Count());

   // finds the single entry where a = 23 and gfs = 11 (A)
   criteria = new[] { "a = 23", "gfs = 11" };
   found = dict.Where(entry => 
        entry.Value.Intersect(criteria).Count() == criteria.Count()).Select(entry => entry.Key);

   Assert.AreEqual(1, found.Count());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this query will work, but I would recommend putting your values into a different data structure than a string. Possibly a struct with the element names so that you can look up multiple values.

```
string s1 = "a = 32, b = 432, f = 321, gfs = 43, d = 42, k = 4, t = 44";
string s2 = "a = 23, b = 432, f = 321, gfs = 413, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314";
string s3 = "a = 23, b = 21, f = 321, gfs = 413, d = 42, k = 4242, t = 4314";
var array = new string[] { s1, s2, s3 };

var result = array.Where(s => s.Contains("f = 321") && s.Contains("b = 432"));
```